# In React Hooks. How to set state to a random number and use that to display a string from an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I'm doing a course to learn React Hooks and i'm stuck on a task.
My task is to create a button that onClick displays a random quote from this array.

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
      {props.anecdotes[selected]}
    </div>
  )
}

const anecdotes = [
  'If it hurts, do it more often',
  'Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!',
  'The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.',
  'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.',
  'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.',
  'Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.'
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <App anecdotes={anecdotes} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I have tried to solve this myself however I encounter errors. Wondered if someone had an easy explanation for this?
Thanks

This is the error I keep on receiving.

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
App
src/App.js:14
  11 | 
  12 | return (
  13 |

> 14 |     Get Random
>        | ^  15 |     {anecdotes[selected]}
>     16 |   
>     17 | )

Comment: Do show your attempted solution along with the errors and we can let you know what the issues might be

Comment: you need to update "selected" on every button click to a random number (0 to anecdotes size - 1)

Comment: Firstly, you don't seem to have a button to click. What errors are you getting?

Comment: This is the error I get when adding a button with onClick(). ×
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Can you do it without hooks? If not, start there, get that working, then it should be pretty clear how to translate that to hooks syntax

Comment: There are already many answers, you can check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution of hooks to pick random value from array**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Example(props) {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const { anecdotes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked and random value from array: <h4>{count}</h4></p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(anecdotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*anecdotes.length)])}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example  anecdotes={[1,4,3,2,8,5]}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Hooks to pick random value from array](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-example-st84y)

Answer (score 1):

So, your App Component receives the quotes, shows the current one already, and based on the selected you want to have a new quote.

The only thing you have to do is to add a button that changes the `selected` value via `setSelected` like so; https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dream-4b3eg

The useState hook provides you 2 arguments, the first one, is to `read` your state, the second one is to `write` your state.

I'm not going to spoiler everything since your are taking a course :) So make the number random, maybe with a additional method, and you will have your expected behaviour.

```
const App = props => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setSelected(4)}>change quote</button> // <=== this addition
      {props.anecdotes[selected]}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However I'm getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: I am stupid, i used the sandbox for something else.

Comment: I updated back again, can you take a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dream-4b3eg

Answer (score 1):

All you need to is generate a random number between 0 and length -1 of the anectodes array.

```
const App = ({anecdotes}) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)

  const handleClick = () => {
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * anecdotes.length);
      setSelected(randomNumber);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick} >Get Random</button>
      {anecdotes[selected]}
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hofstadter-mr01k

Answer (score 1):

**Random Component:**

```
import React, {  useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

const anecdotes = [
  'If it hurts, do it more often',
  'Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!',
  'The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.',
  'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.',
  'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.',
  'Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.'
]

export default function showRandom() {
  const [selected, setSelected]=useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1> {anecdotes[selected]}</h1>
     <button onClick={()=>setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random() * `anecdotes.length))}>Show Random </button>`
      </div>
  );
}
```

**App Component:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import Random from "./showRandom";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Random /></div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: please check, i posted solution as per you requirement.

Comment: Where did you posted?

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/58215414/6544460 and please vote it helps.

Comment: your random generator never generates 0, so it is not correct.

Comment: so are you facing any difficulty?

Comment: @SuleymanSah thanks for your cooperation i have edited my solution. Math.floor will be used instead of Math.ceil

Comment: Also you need to anectodes.length instead of hardoced 5 which should be 6.